# Прямая речь посреди авторских слов

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Здесь прямая речь находится внутри авторских слов, но, по моему, нет определенных указаний на ее введение авторскими словами. В связи с этим вопрос: нужно ли двоеточие после слова "замешательство" или можно ограничиться точкой?

Женщина, вероятно, поняла моё замешательство: «Ваше платье несколько испачкалось. Вы можете взять любое из тех, что висят в гардеробе. Супруг и сын были вынуждены отъехать по делам, а мы с Лизонькой будем рады, если Вы согласитесь присоединиться к нашему чаепитию. Засим позвольте мне оставить вас». Варвара Андреевна поднялась и вышла, закрыв за собой массивную белую дверь с золочёной ручкой в форме чуть приоткрывшегося бутона лилии.

Answer (score 1):

2 Перед прямой речью, следующей за авторскими словами, ставится двоеточие...

3 Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца, то двоеточие после предшествующих авторских слов ставится не всегда.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm

§119. Прямая речь после авторских слов

Comment: Понимаю. Но мой вопрос заключался, по сути, в следующем: можно ли слова "Женщина, вероятно, поняла моё замешательство" считать авторскими словами, вводящими прямую речь?

Comment: Вероятно, нельзя. И если бы прямая речь начиналась с абзаца, то надо было бы ставить точку, а не двоеточие.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно,Аленка, это слова автора. В этом случае глаголы "говорения" (помню нечто подобное у Розенталя) подразумеваются.Он посмотрел на меня (и спросил): "Это ты сделал?". В Вашем предложении "Женщина поняла мое замешательство (и сказала): "Ваше платье несколько испачкалось"

Comment: Спасибо всем большое.

Answer (score 0):

Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца, то двоеточие после предшествующих слов автора ставится не всегда:

> двоеточие ставится, если слова автора содержат глагол со значением речи-мысли (говорить, сказать, рассказать, заметить, обратиться, воскликнуть, закричать, прошептать, спросить, спрашивать, ответить, вставить, прервать, заговорить, начать, продолжать, подтвердить, пояснить, согласиться, поддакнуть, напомнить, посоветовать, упрекнуть, решить, подумать и т. п.) либо существительное, близкое по значению или образованию к глаголам речи-мысли (вопрос, ответ, слова, восклицание, голос, шёпот, звук, крик, мысль и т. п.). ***Д.Э. Розенталь.Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.***

***Как отметил Виктор, здесь подразумеваются глаголы речи-мысли, поэтому после слов автора нужно двоеточие.***

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь пишет на этот счет: "Двоеточие ставится также и в тех случаях, когда в авторских словах нет глаголов речи или заменяющих их глаголов с указанными выше значениями, но ситуация показывает, что вводится прямая речь, например: ...А тот ему: «Этот дом наш общий» (Чехов)".